# How to avoid memory leak with Gorilla sessions on Google App Engine standard environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, memory-leaks, gorilla

I'm using Gorilla to enable session variables on Google App Engine. So far I imported "github.com/gorilla/sessions" only, but Gorilla's page says:

> If you aren't using gorilla/mux, you need to wrap your handlers with
>   context.ClearHandler as or else you will leak memory! An easy way to
>   do this is to wrap the top-level mux when calling http.ListenAndServe:
>
> http.ListenAndServe(":8080",
>   context.ClearHandler(http.DefaultServeMux))

My question is how do I adapt this for the App Engine Standard Environment, which as far as I know does not use http.ListenAndServe by default. My code looks like this:

```
package test

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"   
)

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    var cookiestore =  sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("somesecret"))
    session, _ := cookiestore.Get(r, "session")
    session.Values["foo"] = "bar"

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "session value is %v", session.Values["foo"])

}
```

Would I get a memory leak this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc you quoted tells everything you need to do: wrap your handlers using [`context.ClearHandler()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/context#ClearHandler). Since you "only" have a handler *function* and not an [`http.Handler`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler), you may use the [`http.HandlerFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) adapter to get a value that implements `http.Handler`:

```
func init() {
    http.Handle("/", context.ClearHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handler)))
}
```

You need to do this for every handler you register. That's why the doc mentions that it's easier to just wrap the root handler you pass to [`http.ListenAndServe()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe) (and that way you don't have to wrap the other, non-top-level handlers). But this isn't the only way, just the easiest / shortest.

If you don't call `http.ListenAndServe()` yourself (as in App Engine), or you don't have a single root handler, then you need to wrap all handlers manually that you register.

Note that the handler returned by `context.ClearHandler()` does nothing magical, all it does is call [`context.Clear()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/context#Clear) after calling the handler you pass. So you may just as easily call `context.Clear()` in your handler to achieve the same effect.

If you do so, one important thing is to use `defer` as if for some reason `context.Clear()` would not be reached (e.g. a preceding `return` statement is encountered), you would again leak memory. Deferred functions are called even if your function panics. So it should be done like this:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    defer context.Clear(r)

    var cookiestore =  sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("somesecret"))
    session, _ := cookiestore.Get(r, "session")
    session.Values["foo"] = "bar"

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "session value is %v", session.Values["foo"])
}
```

Also note that the session store creation should only be done once, so move that out from your handler to a global variable. And do check and handle errors to save you some headache. So the final suggested code is this:

```
package test

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "log"

    "github.com/gorilla/context"
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
)

func init() {
    http.Handle("/", context.ClearHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handler)))
}

var cookiestore =  sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("somesecret"))

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, err := cookiestore.Get(r, "session")
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error:
        log.Printf("Error getting session: %v", err)
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    session.Values["foo"] = "bar"

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "session value is %v", session.Values["foo"])
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm getting the following error with the code above: cannot use handler (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) as type http.Handler in argument to "github.com/gorilla/context".ClearHandler:
        func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)

Comment: Thanks, it worked after I deleted the old session cookie (it was saying "securecookie: the value is not valid" before that, probably due to a different prior key being used)

Answer (score 1):

Gorilla also offers a `context.Clear()` option that you can put in your request handler as per the docs here:

https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/context#Clear

So your handler func would become:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    var cookiestore =  sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("somesecret"))
    session, _ := cookiestore.Get(r, "session")
    session.Values["foo"] = "bar"

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "session value is %v", session.Values["foo"])
    context.Clear(r)
}
```