# How can I make type assertions against an anonymous function?

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm writing an HTTP service in Go using Gorilla. I'm newish to Go (<1yr experience), but ramping up fairly quickly.

I have a function I use to register my handlers:

```golang
func (s *Server) RegisterHandler(path string, handler http.HandlerFunc, methods ...string) {
    if len(methods) == 0 {
        s.Router.Handle(path, handler).Methods(http.MethodGet)
    } else {
        s.Router.Handle(path, handler).Methods(methods...)
    }
}
```

I have some code that registers named functions as handlers:

```golang
func (s *Server) RegisterDefaultHandlers() {
    s.RegisterHandler("/ping", Ping)
}

func Ping(w http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    responders.RespondOk(w)
}
```

I also have unit test code that registers anonymous functions as handlers:

```golang
s.RegisterHandler("/testPath", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // whatever the test calls for
}, http.MethodPost)
```

This all works great -- just establishing my starting point.

Today, I find myself banging my head against Go's type system. I am defining some custom handler types, for example:

```golang
type UserAwareHandlerFunc func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, models.User)
```

And I'm also introducing a function to allow me to register such handlers, and to wrap all handlers in `context.ClearHandler`. If this works, I'll also wrap everything with another function that sets a few things on my logging context. What I have so far:

```golang
func (s *Server) RegisterHandler(path string, handler interface{}, methods ...string) {
    wrappedHandler := wrappers.ApplyWrappers(handler)
    if len(methods) == 0 {
        s.Router.Handle(path, wrappedHandler).Methods(http.MethodGet)
    } else {
        s.Router.Handle(path, wrappedHandler).Methods(methods...)
    }
}

func ApplyWrappers(handler interface{}) http.Handler {
    var result http.Handler
    if userAwareHandler, ok := handler.(UserAwareHandlerFunc); ok {
        result = UserAware(userAwareHandler)
    } else if handlerFunc, ok := handler.(http.HandlerFunc); ok {
        result = handlerFunc
    } else if handlerObj, ok := handler.(http.Handler); ok {
        result = handlerObj
    } else {
        log.Fatalf("handler %+v (type %s) is not a recognized handler type.", handler, reflect.TypeOf(handler))
    }

    // to avoid memory leaks, ensure that all request data is cleared by the end of the request lifetime
    // for all handlers -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48203334
    result = context.ClearHandler(result)
    return result
}

func UserAware(handler UserAwareHandlerFunc) http.Handler {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        user := ... // get user from session
        handler(w, r, user)    
    }
}
```

With these changes, I can no longer register named or anonymous functions; the type assertions in `ApplyWrappers` all fail. I have to declare and define a typed variable, then pass that in.

Named functions have two feasible approaches:

```golang
var Ping http.HandlerFunc = func(w http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    responders.RespondOk(w)
}

func Ping2(w http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    responders.RespondOk(w)
}

func (s *Server) RegisterDefaultHandlers() {
    s.RegisterHandler("/ping", Ping)

    var pingHandler2 http.HandlerFunc = Ping2
    s.RegisterHandler("/ping2", pingHandler2)
}
```

For anonymous functions, I can do:

```golang
var handler http.HandlerFunc = func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ...
}
s.RegisterHandler("/testPath", handler, http.MethodPost)
```

The whole point of what I've built here is to consolidate boilerplate into one place, keeping my many tests and handlers as streamlined as possible. The need to declare a typed variable is working against that goal. So my question is this: is there some special type magic I could use (preferably in `RegisterHandler` and/or `ApplyWrappers`) that would restore the ability to pass named and/or anonymous functions to RegisterHandler?

EDIT: thanks so much for the quick answers. Problem solved:

```golang
func ApplyWrappers(handler interface{}) http.Handler {
    var result http.Handler
    if userAwareHandler, ok := handler.(UserAwareHandlerFunc); ok {
        result = UserAware(userAwareHandler)
    } else if anonymousFunc, ok := handler.(func(http.ResponseWriter,*http.Request)); ok {
        result = http.HandlerFunc(anonymousFunc)
    } else if handlerObj, ok := handler.(http.Handler); ok {
        result = handlerObj
    } else {
        log.Fatalf("handler %+v (type %s) is not a recognized handler type.", handler, reflect.TypeOf(handler))
    }

    // to avoid memory leaks, ensure that all request data is cleared by the end of the request lifetime
    // for all handlers -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48203334
    result = context.ClearHandler(result)
    return result
}
```

It's working now, but I still have questions:

1. If I understand correctly, the "duck typing" behavior that I was looking for here would have been fine if I were dealing with interfaces rather than functions. What drives the distinction? Is duck-typing of functions something I could reasonably hope to see in a future version of the language?
2. I can *cast* the anonymous function to a HandlerFunc. It's weird to me that casting and type assertions don't share semantics. Can someone explain?

EDIT 2: I've now seen the bit of the language spec that says that defined types (i.e. ones with names) are never *identical* to any other type, even if the underlying type is the same, and as such will never work in a type assertion (unless it's an interface). So now I'm left wondering:

1. *Why* are the semantics different between interfaces and other types?
2. *Why* are the semantics different for named and un-named types?

I find both to be unintuitive and inconvenient. Am I alone here? I'm wondering if anyone knows why these decisions were made when the language was designed (perhaps it's particularly difficult to implement without bloating the compiler or its output, etc.), and if anyone is aware of plans to address either situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http.HandlerFunc` is a specific type. The `Ping` function is NOT of that type, although it *can* be converted to that type since they both have the same underlying type.

If `handler` is an anonymous function then you need to use an anonymous function in the type assertion:

```golang
f, ok := handler.(func(http.ResponseWriter,*http.Request))
```

---

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions

> - if `T` is not an interface type, `x.(T)` asserts that the dynamic type of `x` is [**identical**](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) to the type `T`
> - If `T` is an interface type, `x.(T)` asserts that the dynamic type of `x` implements the interface `T`.

Comment: Thank you. The thing that wasn't clear to me is that the anonymous function's type doesn't (insofar as the compiler can detect) _implicitly match_ `HandlerFunc`. It's a bit confusing to me that the whole "duck typing" thing works for interfaces but not for all types, and it's also confusing that I can _cast_ the anonymous function to `HandlerFunc` even though the type assertion doesn't work.

Comment: @JakeRobb I updated the answer with a bit from the language spec which may clear up those questions.

Comment: I'm still confused about why the language designers chose to have the semantics be different for casting and type assertions. In particular, why does the presence of a name change these semantics? I find it highly unintuitive. Not that I expect the language designers to be here to answer, but maybe somebody knows where to find a relevant conversation on a language mailing list or something....

Comment: @JakeRobb if it bothers you enough you can head on to the [go-nuts](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts) mailing list and ask there, the language designers and contributors do visit and sometimes even participate.